# Including variables in json of OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java

I'm converting a curl command to a java program, and I'm facing difficulties wherein I pass a variable to a function and have to include that variable as a json value to be passed as a POST request.

In python, I'd do something like this if it makes sense. I'd like to know what's the best way to do this in Java.

```py
data = '{"url":\"%s\"}'%url
```

This is the block of code I'm trying to change right now :

```java
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConn.getOutputStream());
writer.write("{\"name\":\"%s\"}"%content);
```

Passing a string like `writer.write("{\"name\":\"content\"}");` works, however I want to include a variable there.

Comment: I would recommend using [JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) or [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to work with JSON properly to avoid making mistake like when escaping. Like in this case you would get into trouble if `content` contains a `"`, if you directly substitute it.

Comment: As @RickyMo says, creating JSON by string operations is a bad idea.

Comment: You look like you try trying to do python or ruby-like string interpolation in Java.  Java  doesn't support support it.  But even if you did manage it, it would be an incorrect solution because it wouldn't properly escape the `content` string in the resulting JSON ... in cases where escaping is required.

Comment: PS ... that is not correct code in Python either.

Comment: @StephenC Messed up the quotations whilst typing it here, corrected it now.

Comment: @TonyStark - You missed my point.  It is not a Python syntax problem I am talking about.  It is the fact that `context` will be substituted without doing proper >JSON< escaping.

Comment: @StephenC I do understand that. Looking at building a proper json now without string interpolation, guess I'll have to add maven dependencies which I haven't done before :)

Comment: It will be easier to learn how to do dependencies than to write everything yourself.  (And that applies in Python too!)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.format` like this:

```
 String.format("{\"name\":\"%s\"}", "url");
```

or with a variable `context`

```
 String.format("{\"name\":\"%s\"}", context);
```